# Jquery wrap permalink in a data-attribute?

Tags: ajax, javascript, customization

I'm calling the permalink of post on submitting a form like below:

```
       var $this = $(this),
            category = $this.attr('data-event-category'),
            action = $this.attr('data-event-action'),
            label = $this.attr('data-event-label')
             permalink =  call_url["permalink"]


        self.track(category, action, permalink);

                console.log('tracking pushed: '+category+', '+action+', '+permalink+','+label)

    });
},
```

Which I'm calling via my functions.php

```
    wp_register_script( 'analytics', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/analytics.js','','1.0.1');
wp_enqueue_script( 'analytics' );
wp_localize_script(
    "analytics"
, "call_url"
, [
        "permalink" => get_permalink($post),
]
```

);

All works great and appear in my console fine.

Only thing is, I would like it to the permalink to appear as an data-attribute like the category, action and label.

For that I tried the below:

```
                 permalink =  $this.attr('call_url["permalink"]')
```

Which doesn't seems t work.

Any help will be super ??

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

To set an attribute you will need to do

```
 $(this).attr('data-url', call_url["permalink"]);
```

To update

```
$(this).data('url', call_url["permalink"]);
```

Comment: Hi Jim,

Thanks, May I know what is the 'url' referencing to ?

Thanks

Comment: in the console it bring only the value [object Object] instead of the URl with this . ..

Comment: I think you need to filter down through the [object,Object] 
var obj =  call_url["permalink"]
console.log(obj[0].['permalink'])